# Insert multiple attributes into html tag using JavaScript and not between tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From a previous quest we asked about inserting a new attribute into a html tag and the code below does the job nicely, but how should it be coded to add multiple attributes, for example changing..

```
<body bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
```

to...

```
<body bgcolor="#DDDDDD" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
```

The code that works for a single attribute is...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("id", "something");
```

How to modify this for inserting multiple attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as calling it twice:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.setAttribute("topmargin", "0");
body.setAttribute("leftmargin", "0");
```

Comment: In this code is ("body") case sensitive? For example will it still apply if the body tag is in caps like <BODY>?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('body').attr({
  topmargin: 0,
  leftmargin: 0
});
```

Using JS:

Write a function yourself like:

```
    HTMLElement.prototype.setAttributes= function(attrs, values) {
        for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++){
            this.setAttribute(attrs[i] ,+values[i]);
        }
    };

    //And call it like:

    document.getElementById('custom-header').setAttributes(['topmargin','leftmargin'],['0','0'])
```

Answer (score 0):

May By like this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("id", "something");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("topmargin", "0");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("leftmargin", "0");
```